# Is await Task.Run(ioBoundOperation) equals to ioBoundOperation?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, ui-thread

Given the pre-condition that we are on the UI thread, is

```
// doing other stuff
await Task.Run(Long_IO_Bound_Operation);
// do more stuff
```

exactly the same as:

```
// doing other stuff
Long_IO_Bound_Operation();
// do more stuff
```

By "exactly the same" i mean that the end result, including freezing (or not) of the UI are the same?

note: pls refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx before answering

Comment: Just as a side comment, the even better solution is do `await Long_IO_Bound_Operation_Async()`, but that would require re-writing `Long_IO_Bound_Operation` to expose async methods that go down the call stack till you get to the actual IO you are waiting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Task.Run` will spawn a new thread and execute the `Long_IO_Bound_Operation` on that thread freeing up the UI thread for something else. `await` keyword will guarantee the execution comes back to UI thread once task that was created by `Task.Run` completes.

In another words, if you were to not `await` the `TaskRun`, `// do more stuff` would execute right after `Task.Run` statement. But `await` keyword makes sure, `// do more stuff` is delayed until `Long_IO_Bound_Operation` completes on the thread that was spawned by `Task.Run`

```
await Task.Run(SomeProcess);
DoMoreStuff();
```

is the same as:

```
Task.Run(SomeProcess).ContinueWith(t=>DoMoreStuff(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

So no, it's not "exactly the same" in that the first won't block the UI thread whereas the second would.

Comment: `Task.Run` uses the thread pool that manages its own threads. `Task.Run` does not spawn any threads on its own.

Comment: That's just technicality. I could have written "Task.Run requests an available thread from the ThreadPool and executes the method..." which is essentially the same

Comment: Yes. All the work done building efficient thread pools and using them is just a technicality. It's just done for the fun of it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only in the sense that while `Long_IO_Bound_Operation()` is being awaited the UI thread will not completely lock up and have the app display "Not Responding". Exectuion will not continue until `Long_IO_Bound_Operation()` completes, but it won't lock the UI thread.